# Why can't I define both the Test and test classes in one file?

Tags: java

I found that when I define two classes with the same name but different case in the same file, the program will crash.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    }
}

class TestClass {}
class Testclass {}
```

These are the output information:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   top/example/study/Testclass (wrong name:
>   top/example/study/TestClass)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)   at
>   java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1009)    at
>   java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
>     at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:190)
>     at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:499)
>     at com.example.study.Main.main(Main.java:6)

I learned that java is case sensitive, so why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: I have tried this code and not getting error. please check your package details.

Comment: @GauravRai1512 - You're probably using \*nix, then, or at least a case-sensitive file system.

Comment: Defining multiple top-level classes in the same file is something best avoided anyway. As is defining classes that differ only in their capitalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you use Windows, or at least a case-insensitive file system.

Java's compiler generates `.class` files using the name of the class. `TestClass.java` => `TestClass.class`, `Testclass.java` => `Testclass.class`. But if your file system is case-insensitive, `TestClass.class` and `Testclass.class` are the same filename, and one of them overwrites the other.

Instead, make the names different in a way *other* than just capitalization.